# Securing RMI on EhCache

Tags: replication, rmi, ehcache

I am working on a Spring Boot 1.2.5 application running on an external Tomcat 7.5 server that uses a replicated EhCache (using RMI).

I have setup the automatic peer discovery replication using the example provided here http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/replication/rmi-replicated-caching

It works fine. However, the traffic between the nodes seems to be unencrypted (using Wireshark on the Peerlistener port). Is there a way to secure this communication so that it can't be read off the wire? There seems to be nothing on the EHCache documentation about securing this cache replication data.

Also, can I use Spring configurations to setup some kind of shared authorization for the RMI

Comment: This is a ehcache feature, Spring does not have any configuration support for that.

Answer (score 2):

Ehcache RMI replication does not support a secured setup out of the box.

In order to add this support, you will have to dig through the internals to be able to inject a custom socket factory.